# Send an email of my python output using python

Tags: python, smtplib

I am trying to send an email of my output using python. There are no errors in the code I wrote, and an email with no body is being sent. The email's body/context is completely blank. I was hoping that someone could assist me with this.

```
mail_content =[(print ("------------------------------------------------")),
print("this is a test2"),
print("Name="+x)]

#The mail addresses and password
sender_address = 'my internal server'
receiver_address = 'example@example.com'
#Setup the MIME
message = MIMEMultipart()
message['From'] = sender_address
message['To'] = receiver_address
message['Subject'] = 'A test mail sent by Python.'   #The subject line

#Create SMTP session for sending the mail
session = smtplib.SMTP('my internal server', 255) #my internal server with port
session.starttls() #enable security
text = message.as_string()
session.sendmail(sender_address, receiver_address, text)
session.quit()
print('Mail Sent')
```

If I add the following

```
#The body
message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))
```

I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user1/Downloads/scripts.py", line 105, in <module>
    message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\email\mime\text.py", line 34, in __init__
    _text.encode('us-ascii')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: You have no body actually. Try `message.attach(MIMEText('Hello, world', 'plain'))`

Comment: If I write that I get, 
``` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user1/Downloads/scripts.py", line 105, in <module>
    message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\email\mime\text.py", line 34, in __init__
    _text.encode('us-ascii')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'```

Comment: Well, `mail_content` is a list. It needs to be a string...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thank you for the response. I wrote print instead of string because the value of x shall change everytime the code is ran. How do I solve that?